# Postgres - How do I create a custom datatype with array of custom Datatype

Tags: arrays, postgresql, sqldatatypes

I am creating an object data type as follows:

```
CREATE TYPE agg_obj_type AS (
   agg_type  VARCHAR(10),
   agg_value  NUMERIC
);
```

and using it to create an array type:

```
CREATE TYPE agg_array_type AS (
   agg_obj_type[]
);
```

something like this. I do not see it in the Postgres documentation.

Comment: It seems pointless to create a composite type with just one element. But what exactly is your question?

Comment: I am migrating from Oracle to Postgres and need the psotgres alternative to oracle statement "CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE agg_array_type IS VARRAY(4) OF agg_obj_type;

Comment: You don't need that. You just use `agg_obj_type[]` wherever you would use `agg_array_type`. You are aware that there is no `BULK COLLECT` in PostgresSQL, right?

Comment: As Laurenz pointed out: you don't need the additional object type in Postgres. Just declare an array of the `agg_obj_type`. The equivalent to Oracle's "bulk collect" would be something like `select array_agg(...) into array_variable from the_table t` where `array_variable` is defined as `agg_obj_type[]`